# Making a string by reading down a matrix

Tags: python, performance, strings

Suppose I have a string with a length always a multiple of four:

```
'CodeReviewSE'
```

My goal is to create a permutation. First, I arrange the string into a matrix (where each row has a length of 4):

```
    C  o  d  e
    R  e  v  i
    e  w  S  E
```

And then I simply read down, starting from the top-left corner. I get four segments: `CRe`, `oew`, `dvs` and `eiE`. I concatenate them, to get the following string:

```
'CReoewdvSeiE'
```

Reversing the operation is just reversing the steps, kinda. It follows the same steps, except for row length are `len(text) / 4`, and we read down again, to look like this:

```
    C  R  e
    o  e  w
    d  v  S
    e  i  E
```

I've implemented the following code in Python:

```py
import collections

def permute(text):
    # type: (str) -> str

    rows = collections.deque()
    output = ''

    # Create matrix
    for i in xrange(0, len(text), 4):
        rows.append(text[i:i+4])

    # Read matrix downwards
    for counter in xrange(4):
        for row in rows:
            output += row[counter]

    return output


def unpermute(text):
    # type: (str) -> str

    rows = collections.deque()
    output = ''
    length = len(text) / 4

    # Create matrix
    for i in xrange(0, len(text), length):
        rows.append(text[i:i+length])

    # Now read downwards
    for counter in xrange(length):
        for row in rows:
            output += row[counter]

    return output
```

I also ran a performance tests using the `timeit` module, using random strings of different lengths (where `n` is the length):

> ```
> n = 32                                    Best:       |       Avg
> Permute: (10,000 loops, best of 10):     0.06563            0.07080
> Unpermute: (10,000 loops, best of 10):   0.06337            0.06655
>
> n = 64                                    Best:       |       Avg
> Permute: (10,000 loops, best of 10):     0.11592            0.11939
> Unpermute: (10,000 loops, best of 10):   0.10358            0.10530
>
> n = 256                                   Best:       |       Avg
> Permute: (10,000 loops, best of 10):     0.43404            0.44310
> Unpermute: (10,000 loops, best of 10):   0.37202            0.38102
>
> n = 1024                                  Best:       |       Avg
> Permute: (10,000 loops, best of 10):     1.82779            1.85647
> Unpermute: (10,000 loops, best of 10):   1.72195            1.78491
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most important comment: **`permute` is just `unpermute` with `length = 4`.**

There seems to be no reason to favor `collections.deque` over a normal `list` here. It is only an advantage of you do a lot of `queue.popleft()` calls.

For the creation of `rows` you can just use a list comprehension:

```
rows = (text[i:i+4] for i in xrange(0, len(text), 4))
```

I would use a generator expression here to save memory

You could simplify your un-/permute to: something like:

```
def permute(text, n=4, reverse=False):
    n = len(text)/n if reverse else n
    matrix = (text[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(text), n))
    matrix_t = zip(*matrix)
    return "".join("".join(x) for x in matrix_t)
```

where `(text[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(text), n))` makes a generator object that is like your `rows`, `zip(*list)` transposes a list of lists and the two joins first join each row and then the rows.

This will not even create a lot of overhead because they are all generator objects (and therefore it is not one possibly big list being read into memory).

You could even inline all of it:

```
def permute(text, n):
    return "".join("".join(x) for x in zip(*(text[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(text), n))))
```

Comment: "permute is just unpermute with length = 4" should be bolded / underlined in my opinion, merging these functions avoids massive repetition.

Comment: Oh wow. This answer is awesome. I never thought about using `zip` here, and it does exactly what I want to do. The generator objects are better too. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Nah, it's waaay better! With random strings of length 1024, permuting only takes `0.868s` on my machine, way faster than the `1.828s` I had before.

Comment: Yay, that wasnt even my goal :-)